# Set python interpreter for project in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, interpreter

Chances are high that this question already exists, but I could find any useful answers until now:/ The issue is that I have created a new github repository for a new small python project. I would like to work in VS-Code and create an environment with miniconda. All this is no problem. But is there any way to make sure, that always when I open VSCode it automatically switches to this interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Under `.vscode` folder, create a file named `settings.json` and add this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python3.7"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! The `.vscode`-folder is specific for a project? Because I didn't create a "Visual Studio Code"-Project...